# Webpack 3 no scope hoisting and no fallback output with --display-optimization-bailout cli flag

Tags: webpack, webpack-3

upgraded to webpack 3 and using the `ModuleConcatenationPlugin` plugin (followed instructions [webpack 3: Official Release!!](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-3-official-release-15fd2dd8f07b)). i'm not seeing any difference in a diff of my bundle with the plugin added vs without and still seeing all the function closures.

added the `--display-optimization-bailout` flag to for output on why hoisting was prevented, but i don't see any output.

looked around the webpack source a bit and it appears that bailout reasons are not being set because `module.meta.harmonyModule` is falsy, not sure why...
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/optimize/ModuleConcatenationPlugin.js#L42

anyone else have a simliar issue?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but have found no solution or reason yet. very interested in an answer to this.

Comment: Are you suggesting this is a bug in the code? If so, it isn't a question that can be answered here.

Comment: I think there are common thing that can be added to the config that make this not work but webpack does not report what is happening.

Comment: In our case we found the babelrc was overriding some settings we trying to only set for the final build of the app. it was causing the modules to always output in commonjs instead of es6 harmony modules.

Comment: @StefanHayden What was your .babelrc?